# C# HTMLAgilityPack VS regular expressions for extracting links from HTML

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm writing a C# web crawler and when I run the profiling I can see that `HTMLAgilityPack's LoadHTML` method is using 10% of the programs overall CPU usage. I'd like to try and lower this.

I'm sure a regular expression would be faster but as I look at link extracting examples on SO I see everyone saying this method should be avoided in favour of a html parser like `HTMLAgilityPack`.

As all I need to do is extract links from HTML is using `HTMLAgilityPack` over kill?

Are the reasons for favouring a HTML parser applicable to my case as I'm only using it for extracting links?

---

Downloaded HTML with WebClient then compared.

Using `href\\s*=\\s*(?:[\"'](?<1>[^\"']*)[\"']|(?<1>\\S+))` (then trimming and adding to a list) is way faster than HTMLAgilityPack.

43 milliseconds compared to 3 consistently.

---

See my code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/16N9rnNe)

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack` is still better than using `RE`

Comment: If it's about extracting URLs, Regular Expressions are fine.

Comment: You should at least show how you extract the links

Comment: @Adeel could you expand on why please? For this scenario specifically if possible :-)

Comment: To make your pattern easier, use the hex codes of  `\x22` for `"` and \x27 for the single quote `'`. That avoid the hassle of escaping a pattern for the C# compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the reasons for favouring a HTML parser applicable to my case as I'm only using it for extracting links?

In your case the HTML parser is overkill as your tests have shown.

People who answer on SO use that as a *rote* answer to all regex questions. One should use the tool if one actually needs to parse the domain of the HTML in a more robust fashion.

---

**Bias** against Regular Expressions are found by people who feel that they are too slow or cumbersome [to learn]. There is some merit on what is proposed by them for certain operations, in that specific optimized text for finding utilities do perform better. Sure I agree, but to dismiss regex out of hand, well that is par for the course on StackOverflow.

**Why** is that? Sometimes the analysis is simply flawed because the pattern provided introduces a lot of *unnecessary* backtracking and is not optimized. That handicaps regex out of the gate. One does have to learn the regex language and understand what it is doing to tune the engine of regex to not pollute.

**For** example I took your same C# code test, but I used an optimized pattern of yours and my own and was able to get it down to 1 millisecond consistently!

Most people learn basic pattern matching by doing searches with a `*`. When they first learn regex they use `*` with the `.` such as `.*`. That step along with indiscriminate usage of the `*` will most likely will doom any non beginning pattern to the hell of backtracking and slow responses.

Unless you know empirically that there are no items, use the `+` instead.

---

Back in 2009 I wrote about this subject on my blog [Are C# .Net Regular Expressions Fast Enough for You?](http://omegacoder.com/?p=324)